# Why doesn't dragging images using JavaScript work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, dom-events

I'm using the code below for dragging an image (`#StndSoln1`). It works perfectly in Chrome and all, but not in Firefox. Here  startDrag() is the function which i attached to the mousedown event listener. Could anybody please help me.

```
function initialFunction(){


document.getElementById("StndSoln1").addEventListener('mousedown',startDrag,false);
document.getElementById("StndSoln1").addEventListener('mousemove',drag,false);
document.getElementById("StndSoln1").addEventListener('mouseup',stopDrag,false);


}


function startDrag()

{

if (!moveFlag){


currentTraget=document.getElementById("StndSoln1");

offsetX=currentTraget.offsetLeft;
offsetY=currentTraget.offsetTop;
ImgPlaced=false;    
moveFlag=true;

x=window.event.clientX;
y=window.event.clientY; 

event.preventDefault();
}
}

   // Fn for drag the current target object...
  function drag(){

if (moveFlag && !ImgPlaced){    
    currentTraget.style.left=(offsetX+window.event.clientX-x)+"px";
    currentTraget.style.top=(offsetY+window.event.clientY-y)+"px";
}
}
```

Comment: well this code doesn't really do much other than set a few variables.... so idk how it even drags images in chrome.

Comment: When you have misspellings such as Traget instead of Target, I start to question if you will be able to get it working even if someone explained it to you.

Comment: Just as a note to the future, this is why the rest of us use libraries like jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had a similar problem, so I can try to help even without the code you're using.

See, the Firefox developers had this bright idea of making it so that, when you drag an image, you can "move" it around and possibly drop it in an Explorer window to quickly and easily download it, or to the tab bar to open the image in a new tab. The obvious downside of this is that it results in a default behaviour that other browsers don't have.

The simple solution is to make sure that all your events are properly cancelling the default action (`event.preventDefault`, `return false`, that kind of thing). Should that fail too, then you should use a `<div>` element with a `background-image` instead of an `<img>` element.